# Ardenn, Intrepid Archaeologist with reconfigure

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I was curious what would happen if I tried to attach an equipped with reconfigure (like [The Reality Chip](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=The%20Reality%20Chip)) to a creature using the trigger from [Ardenn, Intrepid Archaeologist](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ardenn%2C%20Intrepid%20Archaeologist).

Would it attach since it is an equipment and if so would it still be a creature somehow?

My best guess is that it would equip, but not be a creature just like when you'd reconfigure it, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The Gatherer link for Reality Chip seems to be broken... when I click on it, I'm told that a search returned 0 results. The Ardenn link is OK, though.

Comment: Gatherer doesn't have spoilers/previews.  Once the set comes out, the link will work.

Comment: @AJM it will work in a few weeks when the set is released, Gatherer doesn't usually put up anything until release day or very close to it.

Comment: A lot of other rules forums I have been a part over the years discouraged rules questions based on spoilers of unreleased sets. For the most part many rules questions of new cards can only really be answered with any certainty after the rules FAQ has been released.

Comment: In all honesty even if there is qualified magic judges that are willing to clarify the rules here they are probably going to need the level 5 judges of the world to clarify the rules for them.

Comment: @NeilMeyer Judges are no longer on the old 5 level DCI system, the levels now top out at 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### It will work. Any form of attach will work with creature equipment.

This question has been [answered by Jess Dunks](https://twitter.com/Dunkatog/status/1486777069316960256) on Twitter in reference to [Sigarda's Aid](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sigarda%27s%20Aid), but the answer covered anything that attaches equipment. Jess is the General Rules Manager for Wizards of the Coast:

> Does Reconfigure have a static ability of "While attached, this isn't a creature" as implied by the reminder text? If so, does attaching The Reality Chip with Sigarda's Aid cause it to stop being a creature and stay attached?
>
> > Yes, Sigarda's Aid works with reconfigure! Any effect that attaches a creature with reconfigure to another creature will cause it it to stop being a creature until it becomes unattached. This isn't technically a static ability, just part of the rules for reconfigure.

Jess also [answered a followup question](https://twitter.com/Dunkatog/status/1486783537260875778) about the 0 cost equip granted by [Puresteel Paladin](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Puresteel%20Paladin)

> I have a follow up question. As the Reality Chip has Equipment typing, does that mean it can be equipped for 0 by Puresteel Paladin since Puresteel grants an alternative cost? Meanwhile, [Bruenor Battlehammer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bruenor%20Battlehammer)'s ability would not work (as it doesn't have an equip cost)?
>
> > You have interpreted both of those results correctly, although to be very technical Puresteel Paladin grants a separate equip ability, not an alternative cost.

While we haven't seen the official rules text coming to the CR update yet, this official source answer indicates that no matter how a creature equipment is attached to a creature, it will lose creature as long as it is attached, not only if done with its own reconfigure ability.

---

Now that the set is out we have [the relevant rules](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Reconfigure), 702.151 is the section on reconfigure:

> **702.151** Reconfigure
>
> > **702.151a** Reconfigure represents two activated abilities. Reconfigure [cost] means “[Cost]: Attach this permanent to another target creature you control. Activate only as a sorcery” and “[Cost]: Unattach this permanent. Activate only if this permanent is attached to a creature and only as a
> > sorcery.”
> >
> > **702.151b** Attaching an Equipment with reconfigure to another creature causes the Equipment to stop being a creature until it becomes unattached from that creature

And there is a reference in 301.5, [the equipment section](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Equipment) of the rules for artifacts:

> **301.5c** An Equipment that’s also a creature can’t equip a creature unless that Equipment has reconfigure (see rule 702.151, “Reconfigure”). An Equipment that loses the subtype “Equipment” can’t equip a creature. An Equipment can’t equip itself. An Equipment that equips an illegal or nonexistent permanent becomes unattached from that permanent but remains on the battlefield. (This is a state-based action. See rule 704.) An Equipment can’t equip more than one creature. If a spell or ability would cause an Equipment to equip more than one creature, the Equipment’s controller chooses which creature it equips.

Answer (score 6):

**According to the comprehensive rules change [announcement](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/news/comprehensive-rules-changes-2022-02-09), it will attach and will not be a creature.**

> 702.151
>
> This rule and its subrules define the keyword ability reconfigure....
>
> when an effect attaches an Equipment with reconfigure to another creature, it also causes the Equipment to stop being a creature as long as its attached.

The [release notes](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/kamigawa-neon-dynasty-release-notes-2022-02-09) also include some reconfigure edge cases, including:

> An Equipment creature with reconfigure can be attached to creatures by effects other than its reconfigure ability, such as the activated ability of Brass Squire.

---

The outcome depends on the exact wording of the comprehensive rules for reconfigure.

The basic rules for reconfigure are described in the [NEO Mechanics article](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/kamigawa-neon-dynasty-mechanics-2022-01-27):

> Reconfigure represents two activated abilities and a bit more. First, as a sorcery, you can pay the reconfigure cost to attach the Equipment to a creature you control. You can do this if the Equipment is unattached, or you can do this to move the Equipment from one creature you control to another. This part of reconfigure does exactly what equip does. The "a bit more" is a rule that says an Equipment with reconfigure that becomes attached to a creature stops being a creature itself.

The question hinges on the exact wording of that "bit more":

- If it specifies that an Equipment attached *by a reconfigure ability* stops being a creature while attached, then The Reality Chip remains a creature. Per rule 301.5c and consistent with e.g., animated artifacts that are Equipment, it would immediately be removed again as a state-based action.
- If it simply says that an Equipment *with reconfigure* stops being a creature while attached, then The Reality Chip would stop being a creature, in exactly the same way as if it had used its reconfigure ability.

My guess is that the rule will be closer to option #2. The rest of rule 301.5 does not care about the reason an Equipment is attached to a creature; it treats equip abilities and other effects that happen to attach Equipment the same. This is probably the more intuitive result for most players.

Comment: I read 301.5c as saying that Equipment that is a creature can't be attached at all, not that SBA checks whether Equipment is a creature and remove if so. Without modification of 301.5c, Ardenn instructs the player to do something illegal, and so should be ignored.

Comment: @Acccumulation That may be; I think I was thinking of the more common situation where an already-equipped Equipment is animated.

Comment: The reminder text on the previewed card Simian Sling [here](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/kamigawa-neon-dynasty-mechanics-2022-01-27) seems very clear: *While attached, this isn't a creature.*

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yes, but reminder text is allowed to gloss over unusual rules interactions for the sake of brevity. (I'm pretty confident that in this case it doesn't, but we won't know for sure until the actual rule is released.)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni The reminder text makes it sound like "While attached, this isn't a creature." is part of the activated ability. If the activated ability creates the continuous effect "While attached, this isn't a creature." then Ardenn would not allow attachment. There's also the question of if X causes Y and Y makes X legal, whether that means we can do X.